# How to compare k8s resource in different api

Tags: kubernetes

I want to update my kubernetes cluster from 1.21 to 1.22, I should update ingress resources from v1beta1 to v1, how do I compare the resource definitions of v1beta1 and v1 to know what to update?

Answer (score 1):

You could check on internet first (example: https://docs.konghq.com/kubernetes-ingress-controller/latest/concepts/ingress-versions/ )

Or you could use `kubectl proxy` command to access kubernetes API server locally and navigate through different apiversions.

(And maybe check the `kubectl explain` command, I have to check if we can do this with it)